# can a chef cookbook has only a resource and no recipe

Tags: chef-infra

I need to write a cookbook that calls a recipe of an existing cookbook. In addition to it, it will just have a  resource.

Other cookbooks will call this resource. My question is can a cookbook has only a resource and no recipe.

Comment: Why didn't you just try it? So hard to write no recipe?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is *yes*. There is simply no such restriction that a cookbook has to contain any recipes. You can put libraries or resources or even only attributes into a cookbook.

Comment: One of my worst answers, I know.. ;-)

Comment: without an explanation, this answer may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion. For example, if someone posts a claim like _"The answer is "no"................"_, how would this answer help reader to pick of two opposing opinions? Consider [edit]ing it into a better shape, to meet [answer] guidelines

Comment: It's not my opinion, is my knowledge ;-)

Comment: Oh my.. before you delete an answer to an extra bad question, I've added a bit of detail that there is simply no such restriction. Many useless words that don't say anything besides "sure, it works".

Comment: StackOverflow really doesn't like the simple answers >_<

Comment: @coderanger getting more and more harsh now the chef tag gets more eyeballs